# Where are the default account settings for AD stored?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a ready way to edit the *default* user object for AD? I'm setting some custom attributes in AD and I want the experience for the administrators to be the same if an account is copied versus created new.

I was thinking that I should be able to set a value via ADSI Edit, probably under the Configuration\WellKnown Security Principals area but I haven't seen what I'm after there so far.

Comment: What exactly do you want to configure?

Comment: @jscott - a couple custom attributes, the unix home directory, department, and home drive come to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is create a user with all the settings you want, and then copy the user.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779681(v=WS.10).aspx